# Regex to match characters not only between two specific symbols but also after a single one

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using this regex:

```
/<([^>]*)>/g
```

for calculating the number of characters between `<` and `>` symbols using JavaScript, but I also need to count the number of characters added after a `<` but before closing the successive `>` when a user is typing.

For example:

```
<I need to count this> this not <this yes> and <also this
```

Comment: What about `<also this this is not <this too>`?

Comment: This should be counted as a single string comprised between the first minor than and last major than.

Comment: what is minor than and major than though?

Comment: The < and > symbols

Answer (score 1):

You could use [<([^>]*)](https://regex101.com/r/t9KM3w/2).

- Will capture any character but `>` occuring after a `<`.

Answer (score 0):

Not purely a regex solution but you could do the following , this solution uses the [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) loop and also the [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) method.

```
var newArr = [];
str.match(/<([^>]+)/g).forEach( (e , i) => newArr.push( e.slice(1) ) ); // ["I need to count this", "this yes", "also this"]
```